# Alias that refers to another alias

Tags: cmder

I need to identify an alias command that refers to another alias command in Cmder, for example let's say i define firstAlias like:

```
alias firstAlias=cd blah/blah
```

than i create another alias that uses above alias like:

```
alias secondAlias=firstAlias $t another command
```

I have already tried these options(including above one) but no luck so far:

1. alias secondAlias=firstAlias $t another command
2. alias secondAlias=$firstAlias $t another command
3. alias secondAlias=`firstAlias` $t another command
4. alias secondAlias=%firstAlias% $t another command
5. alias secondAlias=/firstAlias $t another command

any idea appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posted same quastion here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351922/cmder-how-to-use-an-alias-in-another-alias, asked to reply to you as well.

Comment: Updated my question, found maybe-something but can't see how to use it.

Comment: Solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41948988/1579667

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmder : how to use an alias in another alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351922/cmder-how-to-use-an-alias-in-another-alias)

Answer (score 2):

From what it seems you can't use an alias w/ in another alias.  So a workaround is to merely call a .bat file or something with all the commands you want in it.  Kind of a hassle, but that's what I had to do for my scenario.

I created a .bat file and set my alias to call that file.  I put all the commands I cared about in that file...

```
status=%CMDER_ROOT%\config\status.bat
```