# Cmder : how to use an alias in another alias?

Tags: alias, cmder

I would use an alias in another alias in Cmder.

I'm having a nice alias (the first) to a big command, and I would use it inside another one (the second) :

```
mergelocdist=git fetch origin --prune --verbose && git checkout $1 && git merge --ff-only --verbose origin/$2 || git rebase --preserve-merges --verbose origin/$2

mm=mergelocdist master master
```

The aliases are in the Cmder `aliases` file, and I'm on Windows 7 x64.

The topic has already been asked [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213516/alias-that-refers-to-another-alias),with no replies as now.

If you answer to me, please also answer to this guy :)

Found [this](http://www.ceus-now.com/do-aliases-compound-upon-each-other-is-this-all-shells-does-cmder-compound-aliases/), seems to have something to help but I don't figure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benj:
I suspect that you've already found an answer by now, but I see that no one has answered this question, so I will.

If I may make an alternative suggestion to the aliases file.  It looks like you're trying to solve this for git.

The best way I've found to do this in Windows is to edit the `~/.bashrc` file.  On most Windows machines it would be under `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.bashrc`.

You can create a function such as:

```
function MergeLocDistFn {
    local co_branch=$1
    local merge_branch=$2

    echo ">> Debug Command: git checkout ${co_branch}"
    git checkout ${co_branch}

    echo ">> Debug Command: git merge --ff-only --verbose origin/${merge_branch} || git rebase --preserve-merges --verbose origin/${merge_branch}"
    git merge --ff-only --verbose origin/${merge_branch} || git rebase --preserve-merges --verbose origin/${merge_branch}
}
```

Then you can create aliases in the `~/.bashrc` file, like the following:

```
alias mergelocdist=MergeLocDistFn
alias mm='MergeLocDistFn master master'
```

The advantage to this approach is that it will allow you to get really sophisticated with the function and as I'm showing here, debug it as well with echo statements.

See the attached picture of the example output.
[example output from bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etFzm.png)

Note also, if you'd rather do this for a PowerShell prompt, it's even easier to modify the PowerShell profile, just let me know and I'll show you how.

Another note, you can also create a function in the .bashrc for the current branch.  Here's an example function:

```
function current_branch() {
  ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || \
  ref=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return
  echo ${ref#refs/heads/}
}
```

Here's an example of using the current_branch function:

```
alias gpush='git push -u origin $(current_branch)'
```

I hope that his helps, just let me know if you need any clarifications on this.

Comment: Thanks for helping ! I did not found any solution at this time, so thanks again ! I would kiss you if I could.

Comment: Nice shot for a first answer. I put a link to your answer in the comments of the question I linked in mine.

Comment: Great to hear that it is helpful.  

If you want to explore further, I have also blogged about other bashrc techniques at http://erpenbeck.io/2016/10/27/bashrc/.  For example, if your team uses Git upstream remotes, develop/master branches, etc, there is a handy method called a `cloneIt` that will configure it all in one command.  Customize it to your team's Git conventions.